# Internacionalización en Android Studio, resultado en Calculadora IMC

Tags: android, android-studio, internacionalización

Utilizo un vector para dar el resultado del diagnostico. He logrado internacionalizar los EditText, Button, etc. Pero no se me ocurre una manera de internacionalizar mi vector.

Este es el código que utilizo. 
imc = peso / Math.pow(altura, 2);

```
String[] diagnostico1 = {"Desnutrición", "Bajo peso", "Normal", "Sobre peso", "Obesidad", "Obesidad marcada", "Obesidad mordida"};
int[] imcF = new int[]{16, 20, 24, 29, 34, 39, 40};
int[] imcM = new int[]{17, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 41};

if (rF.isChecked()) {
    tVSuImc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (imc <= imcF[0]) {
        diagnostico.setText("" + diagnostico1[0]);
        diagnostico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i <= 5; i++, j++)
        if ((imc > imcF[i]) && (imc <= imcF[j])) {
            diagnostico.setText("" + diagnostico1[j]);
            diagnostico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    if ((imc > imcF[6])) {
        diagnostico.setText(diagnostico1[6]);
        diagnostico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

if (rM.isChecked()) {

    tVSuImc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (imc <= imcM[0]) {
        diagnostico.setText("" + diagnostico1[0]);
        diagnostico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    for (int i = 0, jk = 1; i <= 5; i++, jk++)
        if ((imc > imcM[i]) && (imc <= imcM[jk])) {
            diagnostico.setText("" + diagnostico1[jk]);
            diagnostico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    if ((imc > imcM[6])) {
        diagnostico.setText(diagnostico1[6]);
        diagnostico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has intentado poner el arreglo de textos en un XML? luego accedes a el de una forma similar a esta `textView.setText(R.string.sign_up);` o también de esta `String test = getResources().getString(R.string.sign_up);`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba ingresando estos valores en el archivo strings.xml en la carpeta de resources es algo similar a esto :

```
<resources>
  <string name="test_text">Test</string>
  <string name="clear_text">Clear</string>
  <string name="wifi_connection">The active connection is wifi.</string>
  <string name="mobile_connection">The active connection is mobile.</string>
  <string name="no_wifi_or_mobile">No wireless or mobile connection.</string>
</resources>
```

luego lo debes llamar asi :

```
String wifi = getResources().getString(R.string.wifi_connection);
```